# JW player next and previous button click event in javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, joomla, jwplayer, joomla-extensions

I am using jw player extension in my joomla site . On next and previous button click of the player i want show which of the song from the below list is playing , is there any way ?
Please help if it possible to access jw player next/previous button click event on javascript/jquery
Or how can we customize  jw player next/previous button clicks ?

Comment: I'm afraid there are no events that are called from when the prev/next buttons are pressed/clicked.

Comment: thanks Ethan for your comment , where exactly rhis next button click function happens .
 I mean when cliciking  on next button the playing track will switch to the next one where this functionality happends in javascript , i want to add some extra feature on that clicks

Comment: There is not an event for this, I'm afraid.

Comment: i need to show which playlist number is playing on each next and previous click , is there any way ?

Comment: There is an old demo here that shows something like this - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/contributors/nyboe/JW_API_xmpl_6-2-0-0.html

Comment: Thanks Ethan this is exactly what i wanted
So just need to add javascript event listeners in page ?
just need to call sendEvent() js function onclick right